# DevExpress - Gridview return FormCollection bad format

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

i work with gridview and dynamic generate columns. I have column TimeEdit

```
  settings.Columns.Add(s =>
                {
                    s.FieldName = item.DescriptionType;
                    s.Name = item.DescriptionType;
                    s.Caption = item.DescriptionType;

                    if(item.FormatType == (int)SoftInputDateNum.TimeWithDate)
                        {
                            s.PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = WebApp.Models.TransportDynamicLogic.GetFormatType(item.Type, item.FormatType);
                            s.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.DateEdit;

                            var properties = s.PropertiesEdit as DateEditProperties;
                            properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
                            properties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom;
                            properties.EditFormatString = WebApp.Models.TransportDynamicLogic.GetFormatType(item.Type, item.FormatType);

                        }
                }
```

and I return all collection in form.

```
 public ActionResult AddForm(FormCollection table)
    {
       //SomeLogic
        var date = table["Date"];
    }
```

And i get only format "new(2015,2,3)", but i want format "3.2.2015", because i have set DisplayFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy".

Comment: You get format as `new(2015,2,3)`? o.O

Comment: yes, i dont know why :/ and i can't convert it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

If you want show correct date you need datetime variable for it. No string as I have.